# How could I generate a combinatorial of the lines of an array with several columns?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, combinations, method-combination

I want to get all possible combinations of n lines of an array.
I don't care what order they are, so it's not a permutacion.

**Example:**

I have an array:

```
[(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
```

**Question:**
I want to find all combinations of two lines:

```
[(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
[(1,2,3), (7,8,9)]
…
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` and cast the combinations to a list, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
for x in combinations(lst, 2):
    print(list(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in combination with itertools**

```
import itertools
test = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
for i in range(0, len(test)):
    for j in sorted(np.arange(len(test)-1,i,-1)):
        print(test[i])
        print(test[j])
        print(list(itertools.product(test[i], test[j])))
```